# Simulate Enter/Submit key press JavaScript

Tags: javascript, input, google-chrome-devtools

I'm confused how something that simple can be so complicated.

Lets take the StackOverFlow search box as an example.
Its an Input field I target with:

```
const inputElement = document.querySelector('input[name="q"][role="combobox"]');
```

then I call:

```
inputElement.value = 'yourSearchValue';
inputElement.focus();
inputElement.dispatchEvent(new KeyboardEvent('keypress', { key: 'Enter', charCode: 13, bubbles: true, cancelable: true }));
```

Which is not working.

This is also not working:

```
inputElement.value = 'yourSearchValue';

const keydownEvent = new KeyboardEvent('keydown', {
    'key': 'Enter',
    'code': 'Enter',
    'charCode': 13,
    'keyCode': 13,
    'which': 13,
    'bubbles': true,
    'composed': true
});
inputElement.dispatchEvent(keydownEvent);


const keyupEvent = new KeyboardEvent('keyup', {
    'key': 'Enter',
    'code': 'Enter',
    'charCode': 13,
    'keyCode': 13,
    'which': 13,
    'bubbles': true,
    'composed': true
});
inputElement.dispatchEvent(keyupEvent);
```

What am I missing, why is it not working?
I tried all kinds of different input field on different websites.
The code above is not working anywhere.

Comment: You can't send keystrokes with JS, if that's your intention. If it isn't, please define "_is not working_", describe what you want your code to do, and what it does instead.

Comment: It should do the same as if I press the Enter key on my keyboard.
So in the example of the StackOverFlow search bar it should submit the search query and start searching

Comment: Like said, you can't do that. `dispatchEvent` only calls the attached event listener(s), it doesn't cause real Enter stroke (it's the real key stroke causing the submission, the event(s) it fires is only a side-effect). You can attach a keydown listener ([keypress is deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/keypress_event)) to the input or the form, and then in the handler, call [`submit`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/submit) method of the form containing that input.

Comment: ... or just call `click` method of the submit button of the form.

Comment: Try the deprecated document.execCommand, [example](/a/57900849).